# AWS: ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTransformJob operation: Could not find model

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, deepar

I am new here and am strugling with some basic things.
I am trying to implement a DeepAR model, but maybe due to an update from sagemaker it doesn't find the correct path as it did on the example..
Can someone tell me why is it happening and how o fix it?

Error: ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTransformJob operation: Could not find model "arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-central-1:900386373554:model/forecasting-deepar-2022-06-21-14-12-51-560".

This is the Batch Transformation I am trying to implement:

-Batch Transform
import boto3
-Create the SageMaker Boto3 client
boto3_sm = boto3.client('sagemaker')

import time
from time import gmtime, strftime

batch_job_name = 'Batch-Transform-' + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())
input_location = 's3://sagemaker-eu-central-1-900386373554/deepar-rossmann/input/prediction_input.json'
output_location = 's3://{}/{}/output/{}'.format(bucket, prefix, batch_job_name)

request = 
{
"BatchStrategy": "SingleRecord",
"MaxPayloadInMB": 100,
"Environment": {
"DEEPAR_INFERENCE_CONFIG" : "{ "num_samples": 200, "output_types": ["mean"] }"
},
"TransformJobName": batch_job_name,
"ModelName": 'forecasting-deepar-2022-06-21-14-12-51-560',
"TransformOutput": {
"S3OutputPath": output_location,
"Accept": "application/jsonlines",
"AssembleWith": "Line"
},
[...]

I am following this project: https://github.com/CatherineSai/project_sales_prediction_DEEPAR
Notebook 3 of 3 step 49

--> ModelName is copied from the finished training job at aws console

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to launch a SageMaker Batch Transform Job you require a `SageMaker Model`. Kindly confirm that the `ModelName` you are passing exists in the `Models` page in the Console (Inference tab  > Models)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Marc!

I thought it was saving it in S3 and was using an link to it...

Now I found the correct link to the model as you described and it worked!
Many Thanks and Best Regards,
Samuel